# Replace first occurence of string b after string a

Tags: bash, sed, command-line

I want to search a number of files (cpp-code) for a certain string A and replace the next occurence of string B with string C.

**Example:

```
traceDebug( "text" ) );
```

**Result to be:**

```
traceDebug( "text" );



String A = "traceDebug"

String B = ") );"

String C = ");"
```

So the first `occurence of ") );` should be replaced by `);`.

I can't simply remove a `)` because there are constellations in files where the syntax is wrong if I would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with a Perl one-liner:

```
perl -i.bak -pE 'BEGIN { undef $/; } s/traceDebug.+?\K\) \);/\);/gs' whatever_files*.cpp
```

**Edit** To run this over files in subdirectories, in `bash`, the easiest is probably:

```
( shopt -s globstar ; perl -i.bak -pE 'BEGIN { undef $/; } s/traceDebug.+?\K\) \);/\);/gs' **/*.cpp )
```

Example input:

```
traceDebug ( "text" ) );
traceDebug
( "text" ) );
) );

do_not_replace (3 * ( 4 + 5 ) );
```

Example output:

```
traceDebug ( "text" );
traceDebug
( "text" );
) );

do_not_replace (3 * ( 4 + 5 ) );
```

Explanation:

- `-i.bak`: In-place editing; original file saved as `foo.cpp.bak`
- `BEGIN { undef $/; }`: Don't break lines, but instead read in the entire file at once
- `s/traceDebug.+?\K\) \);/\);/gs`: Do the replacement.

  - `traceDebug.+?`: Take as little as possible (`.+?`) following a `traceDebug`
  - `\K`: leave that part out of the upcoming replacement
  - `\) \);`: What we want to change (after the `\K`)
  - `\);`: the replacement
  - `/gs`: replace all matches (**G**lobal), and permit the `.` to match newlines as if the whole string were a **S**ingle line

After the `s///gs` runs, Perl itself takes care of renaming the input file to `.bak` and saving the output under the original filename.

Comment: Nearly perfect. But how to run the script recursively on all cpp-files in a directory+subdirectory.

Comment: @gema31 Updated.  If you have other needs, would you please accept an answer to this question and ask a separate question linking to this one?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$ cat foo.txt
traceDebug ( "text" ) );
ignoreMe ( "text" ) );
traceDebug
( "text" ) );
) );
$ sed '/traceDebug/s/) );/);/;t;/traceDebug/,/) );/s/) );/);/' foo.txt
traceDebug ( "text" );
ignoreMe ( "text" ) );
traceDebug
( "text" );
) );
```

The `t` is a conditional branch which ignores the range substitution if the single-line substitution changed the line. Personally I start thinking about using a tool other than `sed` if I need to use branching!

Comment: This works only partially. I have strings where the ") );" is in the next line because of the length.

Comment: @gema31 `I have strings where the ") );"` - then please post example input file with all the corner cases you want to handle with expected output file.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/traceDebug/{:a;s/) );/);/;t;n;ba}' file
```

Narrow the processing to a line containing `traceDebug`. Thereafter substitute `) );` with `);` and bail out. Otherwise print the current line, fetch the next and repeat until successful.